# calculate the order of $[1071]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am given this exercise:

In the group $(\mathbb{Z}_{7623},+)$, calculate the order of $[1071]$.

Formulate the theorem that you used, in its general form, for a multiplicative group $G$ and explain how you applied the theorem at the specific case,where we have addition,instead of multiplication.

Could you give me a hint what a theorem I could use??

Comment: You can look up "Fundamental theorem of cyclic groups". Hint: what is the gcd of 1071 and 7623?

Answer (score 1):

Lemma 1: If $\gcd(m,n)=1$ then the order of $[m]$ in $(\mathbb{Z}_{n},+)$ is $n$.

Lemma 2: For arbitrary $d\in\mathbb{N}$, the order of $[m]$ in $(\mathbb{Z}_{n},+)$, is equal to the order of $[dm]$ in $(\mathbb{Z}_{dn},+)$

The theorem you want combines these two lemmas.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$|\mathbb Z_{7623}| = 3^2\cdot 7\cdot 11^2$$

$$1071 = 3^2 \cdot 7 \cdot 17$$

What is $d = \gcd(1071, 7623)\;?$

Use the [Fundamental Theorem of Cyclic Groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_cyclic_groups#Finite_cyclic_groups) to answer your question, noting that our operation in this group is addition.